# Can one zone file contain multiple domains?

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name, nameserver

I know a DNS server can manage multiple zone files. But can a zone file manage multiple domains? Or each domain must be put in a separated zone file? Those shared hosting companies use a pair of name servers to manage multiple domains. How do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible to use a single zone file for multiple domains, if all the
domains share the same DNS entries, and especially the same IP addresses.

As an example :

```
zone "domain1.com" {
  file "mydomain.com.zone";
};

zone "domain2.com" {
  file "mydomain.com.zone";
};
```

Some rules for the contents of the shared file:

1. Don't include a `$ORIGIN` statement - it's implicit from the config file
2. Use '`@`' to refer to the implicit `$ORIGIN`
3. Use relative domain names (not FQDNs) as appropriate.
4. Use FQDNs when it actually matters which domain is returned

An example for this file would be:

```
@      IN      SOA      data
       IN      NS       ns.example.com.
mail   IN      MX       mail.example.com.
web    IN      A        1.2.3.4
www    IN      CNAME    web
ftp    IN      CNAME    web
```

References:

- [Bind MX record question](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/bind-mx-record-question.48148/)
- [One Zone file for two domains](https://serverfault.com/a/142548)
- [Two domains in one DNS zone file](https://serverfault.com/questions/974839/two-domains-in-one-dns-zone-file)